# Determines .msg attachment is opened in outlook window

Tags: email, outlook, vsto

Is there a way to determine whether or not a mail message that is opened in outlook window is a .msg attachment? I couldn't find anything usefull in the  Outlook.MailItem object.

In other words, I have a mail item that has a .msg attachment in it.
Outlook opens a seperate message window when I double-clicked on the .msg attachment. The question is, is there a way to know whether or not the message is an attachment?

Thank's in advance.

Cheers,

Inoel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reliable way to do that - you can check if MailItem.EntryId is empty, but it is also empty for the brand new unsaved messages. You can also check if MailItem.Sent is true. I don't know if there can be other cases when a message is sent yet does not have an entry id.

Comment: For my need is the check on MailItem.EntryId empty more than enough, thanx.